# Git Can't set the first depot

Tags: git, github

i've read some tutorials about how installing a git depot (repository) and i start on it , i've create a project (of example with a readme.txt file)  , then the above commands :

```
cd project
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'

cd ..
git clone --bare project project.git
```

then in the client side , i try to get the project in local and add some edits the commit it and push to the remote version :

```
git clone git@server:project.git
cd project
vi readme.txt
git add readme.txt
git commit -m 'msg for the first edit'
git push origin master
```

No error is shown , seems that everything is great , but in the server side i can't see the edition in readme.txt file and neither the commit i've did with the command :

```
git status
```

Remarq : i can see the commit done in the project.git and not in the project repository ... plz need some explaination and help
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so let me see if I get this straight:

1. you have 2 machines (let's call them `PC1` and `PC2`)
2. you create a regular git repository on `PC1` named `project`
3. you create a bare repository on `PC1` (`project.git`) by cloning `project`
4. on `PC2` you clone from `project.git` (the bare repo)
5. make changes on `PC2` and push to `project.git` on `PC1`
6. check `project` (the repo from which you created the bare one) on `PC1` and see that the changes aren't there.

If that's correct, then the reason you don't see any changes in `project` on `PC1` is because you don't have it synced with `project.git`. To do this, on `PC` in `project` you need to `git remote add origin git@server:project.git` to have it as a remote, and then do a `git pull origin master` to update it with the changes held in `project.git`.

`project` doesn't automatically update then `project.git` gets updated from another party (in your case `PC2`), and because you first created `project` and then `project.git` (your bare repo), `project.git` wasn't declared a remote.

Think of `project.git` as a storage space for your changes. In order to update your local repository `project`, you need to ask the storage space if there's anything new there (`git fetch` followed by `git pull`, or `git pull` directly).

On `PC2`, because you created the repository by cloning from `project.git`, you already have the remote set, so you can push/pull.

Comment: First thanks for your reply , i really appreciate it , ok you say that i need to add remote i add it in the PC1 ( the server ) ?

Comment: @user3911183 if step `6` is correct (you can't see the changes pushed from `PC2` in the original repo on `PC1`) then most likely that is the case. You can check by going to `project` on `PC1` and running `git remote -v` and checking if it returns anything.

Comment: here is the result of git remote -v : in PC2 : $ git remote -v
origin  git@192.168.110.128:depot.git (fetch)
origin  git@192.168.110.128:depot.git (push) , in PC1 it returns anything

Comment: @user3911183, yes, that means that no remotes are set for the repository on `PC1`. You need to run `git remote add origin git@server:project.git` and then `git pull` to see the changes you pushed from `PC2`.

Comment: yep it's working , thanks a lot . now i would like to understand some thing , the steps i did are corrects ??

Comment: @user3911183 the steps you did are correct overall. Basically you started from a regular repository (`project`) and created a bare copy (you can't push to a regular repository, just to bare ones, that is, ones which don't actually contain the files in the working space). All is good so far (you could push/pull from `project` on `PC2`), but because of the order you used to set up the project, `project` on `PC1` didn't know of the bare repo's existence.

Comment: @user3911183 an easier way to do things is to start by creating the bare repository using `git init --bare project.git` and then cloning it on both `PC1` and `PC2`. This way the remotes are automatically set when cloning.

Comment: ok thanks so much ,here still have a problem , do i need to do : git pull origin master in the server (PC1) every time i make a commit in PC2 or from an other PC ??

Comment: @user3911183 yes, or you could look into [git post-receive hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) to automate checking out the code when a push is done to `project.git` on `PC1`.